# Query: Find customers who have made purchase of every type of flower offered by shop

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to Find customers who have made a purchase on every type of the flower bouquets offered by the shop.  **Output schema**: (Cust)

Find distinct customers in the database who have not made any order during year 2017. You can compare date values by the standard operators <, >, <=, >= 
**Output schema**: (Cust, CName)

Table Names:

**Flowers** (Prod, Name, Description, Price)
**Customer** (Cust, CName, CAddress, CCity, CZip, CState, Card, CardNo, Exp)
**Order** (Order, Prod, Cust, Date, RName, RAddress, RCity, RZip, RState)

What is the solution for these two queries?

Comment: The question in your title is not the same as the one in your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like homework to me 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first query, You can try below -

```
SELECT C.CName
FROM Customer C
JOIN Order F ON C.CUST = O.CUST
JOIN Flowers F ON F.PROD = O.PROD
GROUP BY O.CUST
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PROD) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PROD) FROM Flowers)
```

For second query, You can try -

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CUST, C.CName
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.CUST NOT EXIST (SELECT 1
                        FROM Order O
                        WHERE O.CUST = C.Cust
                        AND YEAR(Date) = 2017);
```